# Is storing encryption info in uri a good idea?

Tags: architecture, uuid, system-design

In a web backend server, I want to **design a pattern of image/video uri**, which is also the key to get the file content from a Object storage.

My idea is concatenating the UUID and some important encrypted file info like `{UUID}_{encrypted_info1}_{encrypted_info2}.jpg`, for example, `Efr5YlfUwAYDdBs_jJFKfda_fdjaJFD1fd.jpg`.

The reason is:

- "UUID" is for uniqueness
- "some important encrypted file info" is for that these info can be accessed without MySQL DB and it can help improve the performance.

So is it a good idea/design?

Comment: Could you please elaborate in which way it should improve performance? Would you search through the files by name instead of accessing the database?

Comment: The video and images access from user will go through an API gateway service that need to query some infomations in MySQL by the file name, for now is UUID. But for better performance, I consider that store the necessary encryption infomations in the filename, so it doesn't need to access MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally not recommend this architecture:

1. SURFACE OF ATTACK: Do not expose encrypted information to public channels when it's not required. In security, you must always think in terms of multiple layers of defense, none of them being 100% secure.
2. DYNAMIC SECRETS: You are not using dynamic keys. With encryption, you must always consider the scenario that your keys will be compromised someday (that's why TLS or IPSEC protocols negotiate temporary symmetric keys). It can be as simple as an employee leaving the company and who is not supposed to be able to decrypt the data anymore.
3. COUPLING RESOURCE LOCATION / DATA MODEL: What if the "important file info" are updated in the DB? How do you know that the information are still up-to-date for a given file?